# Initialize an arrayList with zeros

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

I am creating an `ArrayList` and its size is `40`

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList= new ArrayList<>(40);
```

How can I initialize `myList` with zeros `0` ? I tried this

```
for(int i=0; i<40; i++){
   myList.set(i, 0);
}
```

but I get

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.fill(List<? super T> list,T obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill%28java.util.List,%20T%29) method to fill your list with zeros. In your case you are setting [`new ArrayList<>(40)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) here `40` is not length of the list but the initial capacity. You can use array to build your list with all zeros in it. Checkout following piece of code.

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[40]));
Collections.fill(myList, 0);//fills all 40 entries with 0"
System.out.println(myList);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 13):

Try `Collections.nCopies()`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(40, 0));
```

OR:

```
List<Integer> myList = Collections.nCopies(40, 0);
```

See [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T))

Comment: This is more suitable according to me. +1 Nice one.

Comment: Note that the second example returns an immutable list - which is probably why it should be wrapped in an ArrayList as shown in the first example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.add(0)` instead. The [`ArrayList(int capacity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)) constructor sets an initial capacity, but not initial items. So your list is still empty.

Comment: Note that `Arrays.asList(new int[40])` return `List<int[]>` so your above statement will give compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

There you could have rather **added** than setting. `myList.add` will work. You can set only if there is already an entry on that particular index. **`set`** method only replaces the content present at that index.
[Check api documentation for set method here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E))

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 implementation:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = IntStream.of(new int[40])
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Collections.nCopies` is much better